# App Record creation error I have found this issue while updating my app in App Store

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

[image]

> App record creation error
> App record creation failed due to an invalid attribute. Request failed with error code "ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID. DUPLICATE", and reason "The provided entity includes an attribute with a value that has already been used The SKU you entered has already been
> used."

> App record creation error
> App record creation failed due to an invalid attribute. Request failed with error code "ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID. DUPLICATE", and reason "The provided entity includes an attribute with a value that has already been used The Bundle ID you entered has already been
> used."

I have found this issue while updating my app in the App Store. How do I solve this issue? I have created certificate and profile with the same bundle id but I am still facing issue.